# Why doesnt my app state render to the app in angular Ngrx

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

How do I get the state to render when the app loads? When I run this app the state is empty until I click the button with the click function. I tried doing this.store.select but I never get the requested state. Todo_List is an object inside ngrx store I want to render its list property which is an array

App.Component.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from './AppState.model';
import { Add_Todo, Load_Todos } from './ngrx.actions';
import { Todo } from './ngrx.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>,private http:HttpClient ){
  }
  todo_list$: Observable<Array<Todo>>
  loading$: Observable<Boolean>;
  ngOnInit(): void{
    console.log(this.store)
    this.store.dispatch(new Load_Todos());
    console.log(this.store)
    this.todo_list$ = this.store.source._value.Todo_List.list
    this.loading$ = this.store.source._value.Todo_List.loading
  }
  title = 'angular-todo-list';

  click(){

  //   console.log(this.store)
  //   this.store.dispatch(new Add_Todo({
  //     message: 'heyyyyy',
  //     time: '3pm',
  //     date:'05/16/20',
  //     user_id: 1,
  // }));

  this.todo_list$ = this.store.source._value.Todo_List.list
}
}
```

App.Component.ts

```
<button (click)="click()"id="enter"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="listItems col-12">
                <ul class="col-12 offset-0 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
            <li *ngFor="let x of todo_list$">{{x.message}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things I’m noticing:

1. If you want data out of the store, you have to use a selector. Check out the ngrx.io website for exact instructions and examples. But it looks something like this: `todos$ = this.store.pipe(select(getTodos));`
2. NgRx is Reactive Extensions for Angular, so the selectors return Observables. To display these on the component template, you need to use the `async` pipe like so:

   {{ todos$ | async }}

This takes care of subscribing and unsubscribing from the observable.

Start with those, and hopefully things will start to take shape.

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn add @ngrx/store
```

Run this command in angular CLI.

Comment: How is this supposed to fix the issue?

Comment: Firstly, I downloaded ngrx lib with npm but there was a problem. Then I used yarn for downloading lib. So, It was solved the problem. Because, Yarn and npm can be different versions. Maybe it's because your package works with yarn because it's not running on a different version of npm.